# Resize Controls Proportionally to Form

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

How do I resize controls proportionally to how the form is resized? I have tried anchor and dock properties, but they don't give the result I want.

For example, I have two DataGridViews. I want one to always take up 25% of the screen and the other to take up 75%, no matter how the form is resized. Anchors and docks only stick controls to the sides of the form, but I want the control to take up a specific percentage of space.

Comment: look up docking controls also do a google search on sizing controls to a form. we do not need a screen shot.. but showing us code / what you have tried would help.. use panels also if you want datagrid views to be inside of a container.. look up how to size columns in a datagrid view as well.. lots of free information out there on the web do a google search first before coming here to look for quick fixes / answers..

Comment: No, there is no inbuilt way to do that. You'll have to do it manually; simply resize your controls on your form's `Resize` event.

Comment: Look into the [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-overview) control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492143.aspx). You can decide either during runtime or design time how many rows and columns you want. You can specify their height and width using percentage or a specific number.